# Lenovo T400 ThinkPad display has black spotlights at bottom

Tags: display

There are multiple black shadows appearing on the bottom of my display, like black headlights glowing outwards from the bottom. Sometimes it disappears but now it has appeared again. Any idea what's happening?

Images:
[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: Take it back to the shop if in warranty

Answer (score 0):

This is normally caused by damaged matrix nest. The LED stripe that highlights the matrix is sometimes in front of the thin foil that scatters the light all over the whole surface. If your device is new and you did not damaged it - please use you warranty.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have warranty, but I saw the similar problem and its solution here:http://support.apple.com/en-us/TS1258